# How to Get/Expect Terminal Commands run in C++ program

Tags: c++, terminal

I'm writing a program which runs commands in the Terminal. I want to be able to look at the last command run at any point in time. As in, I don't know what command has just been executed, what command was it? This needs to be in C++.

Comment: What OS? In unix, you can use `history`

Comment: Is there an alternative to history?

Comment: Again, it depends on what OS you're targeting

Comment: I'm using an Ubuntu machine.